# webkit executesql sentence and loop problem

Tags: javascript, webkit, closures

I'm trying to use loop variable in executeSql function that contained by loop. But loop variable gets the last value if i don't use a closure. When i use a closure , i don't get the result list from executeSql function. Examples:

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT AColumn FROM ATable WHERE refID=' + i, [],
function(tx,results) //success function
{
//do something
}
,errorfunction);

}
```

In success function "i" is always "count+1".

To solve this i changed my code like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT AColumn FROM ATable WHERE refID=' + i, [],
(function(tx,results) //success function
{
//do something
})(i)
,errorfunction);
}
```

With this, i get the "i" right. But "results" is undefined.

I tried to pass "tx" and "i" like this:

```
    (function(tx,results) //success function
    {
    //do something
    })(tx,null,i)
```

With this i understand why i get "results" as null. I want to learn how can i get the right results of executeSql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   tx.executeSql('SELECT AColumn FROM ATable WHERE refID=' + i, [],
      (function(i){
         return function(tx,results) //success function
         {
            //do something
         };
      })(i),
   errorfunction);
}
```

At the end of the day you need to pass a function of the signature `function(tx,res)` which is clearly what that whole `(function(i){ return function(tx,res){ ... }; })(i)` does, since the outer anonymous function executes immediately and returns a function of that signature.

The value `i` in that inner function has the value of `i` when the outer function was called (i.e. the value of each iteration), since the value `i` is passed by value into the outer anonymous function, so references to `i` in the returned inner function will resolve correctly.

Comment: not working for me. I have posted my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313901/query-in-loop-not-working-for-ios