# Scoping issue getting a function handle into a jquery click event function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Closure Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569005/javascript-closure-problem)

In the following code, `TrueThis.aChoices[i]['CallBack']` is a function when the click event is created and "false" when the click event actually occurs. How do I get the function reference into the click event handler?

**My Object:**

```
ATK.MultiChoiceDialog = function() {

   var TrueThis = this;
   var aChoices;

   this.Show = function(sTitle,sPrompt,aChoices){
      this.aChoices = aChoices;

      var HTML = '[snip]';
      $('body').append(HTML);

      for(var i in this.aChoices)
      {      
         console.log(TrueThis.aChoices[i]['CallBack']); // shows "function"
         $('#ATKDialogButton'+i).click(function(e){
            console.log(TrueThis.aChoices[i]['CallBack']); // shows "false" ???
            if(TrueThis.aChoices[i]['CallBack'])
            {
               TrueThis.aChoices[i]['CallBack'].call(aChoices[i]['Context']);
            }
         });      
      }
   }
};
```

**I've also tried this:**

```
for(var i in this.aChoices)
{      
   var CB = TrueThis.aChoices[i]['CallBack'];
   console.log(CB); // function
   $('#ATKDialogButton'+i).click(function(e){
      console.log(CB); // false
      if(TrueThis.aChoices[i]['CallBack'])
      {
         TrueThis.aChoices[i]['CallBack'].call(aChoices[i]['Context']);
      }
   });      
}
```

Comment: i is incrementing to the last value of i, so for all click events, i will be the last item iterated through rather than the one when the event was bound.

Comment: if you need to use the value of the loop variable inside a callback for a handler within the loop, you should enclose the binding within a closure that gets sent the variable, or create a separate function that takes the variable as an argument and call the function in the loop

Comment: @ruakh search for "infamous loop problem"

Comment: `CB = TrueThis.aChoices[i.valueOf()]['CallBack'];` ?

Comment: @GGG: It's too late to tell *me* to search, because I'd already voted to close, and I can't change the question I listed. But if you post a specific link to what you think is the best dupe, it might lead other users to vote better.

Comment: @ruakh I could have written *next time* search for "infamous loop problem," but then it sounds like I'm being an ass ;)

Comment: @shhac That doesn't work because `i.valueOf()` gets evaluated when the event runs. It always returns the last iteration.

Comment: @GGG: Ah, O.K.; next time, I'll try to remember that. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a built-in way of handling this by passing event data to the callback function being bound to the event.

```
ATK.MultiChoiceDialog = function() {

   var TrueThis = this;
   var aChoices;

   this.Show = function(sTitle,sPrompt,aChoices){
      this.aChoices = aChoices;

      var HTML = '[snip]';
      $('body').append(HTML);

      for(var i in this.aChoices){ // in js the '{' should be on same line
         console.log(TrueThis.aChoices[i]['CallBack']); // shows "function"
          $('#ATKDialogButton'+i).click({i:i},function(e){ // data passed in with {i:i}
            console.log(TrueThis.aChoices[e.data.i]['CallBack']); // shows "function" 
            if(TrueThis.aChoices[e.data.i]['CallBack']){ // in js the '{' should be on same line
               TrueThis.aChoices[e.data.i]['CallBack'].call(aChoices[e.data.i]['Context']);
            }
         });      
      }
   }
};​
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know the `click` function could do that.

Comment: afaik all jQuery event binding methods now have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, I've got this working. First create a new function to "fix" the value of i, which returns the function for the event handler.

```
this.FixI = function (i){
   return function(e){
      if(TrueThis.aChoices[i]['CallBack'])
      {
         TrueThis.aChoices[i]['CallBack'].call(TrueThis.aChoices[i]['Context']);
      }
   }
}
```

Use the new function to generate the even handlers function in the loop:

```
for(var i in this.aChoices)
{
   $('#ATKDialogButton'+i).click(TrueThis.FixI(i));      
}
```

**UPDATE:** It looks like Kevin B found a Jquery way of addressing the problem that doesn't require an extra "preserver" function.