# sqlite synchronous

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

i have been using sqlite, phonegap, javascript and i m in need of fetching information from the sqlite db.

I am able to fetch all info i need, insert, update, etc.

The problem is javascript works asynchronously. That is it is processing all other succeeding statements before all the necessary info from database gets fetched.

i have tried using callbacks all along and i am tired of it since there are difficulty in using loops. (not able to use sqlite queries within loops since loop gets iterated before the current sqlquery gets processed which is not what i want)

is it possible to do these db operations synchronously?

**UPDATE**
Found out a new solution from here: [webkit executesql sentence and loop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492564/webkit-executesql-sentence-and-loop-problem/14394809#14394809)

Comment: Check out [caolan/async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to help you manage your async operations (such as doing async operiations in a loop in series).

Comment: Have you figured out how to use asynchronous functions inside a loop? I have exactly that problem currently

Comment: @kim366 What I ended up finally doing is remove loops and change it all to function calls which was not elegant. You can try the new await function in javascript to help you out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await  Or you can read this article: https://blog.lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795

Comment: @VigneshT.V. Yup, that's what I'm attempting to do. I switched to `sqlite` (from `sqlite3`), which uses promises. Still trying to get it to work, but it seems promising; pun not intended.

Comment: Finally got it working! With `await` you can just make the asynchronous stuff synchronous and not get a headache with all of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but there's a library that may help...

http://html5sql.com/

I've just started using it myself and it allows you to execute multiple or single SQL requests, with 1 callback.  It may be just what you need :)

Comment: thanx for your quick response. the library you referenced is good but does not allow to do async operations inside a loop in a synchronous fashion.. since, i am doing the queries inside a loop, using call backs are not advisable.

Comment: You cannot do the call synchronously.  If it's in a loop then you must call a function that calls itself with each execute callback.

Comment: oh.. thats what i am currently doing and asked this question only because the code is going too long doing that.. anyways, thanx a lot..

Comment: No worries.  It bugs me a little that it's not a synchronous call, but everything's asynchronous these days, isn't it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Siminov Framework](http://siminov.com). It allows you to make both Synchronous/Asynchronous calls to the native SQLite database. It supports most of the Hybrid Frameworks such as ([Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/), [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/))

However if you are building a Hybrid Apps using JavaScript, then I would recommend to use Asynchronous calls because it has a performance advantage over Synchronous calls.